# Google Analytics Android Realtime working but no data in Reports

Tags: android, google-analytics

This is really baffling as I **can see Real time data** but then **no data is shown in Reports**.

Codes: I have an application class which has all the Analytics code. An xml with all the settings.

**Application.java**

```
public class ApplicationClass extends Application {

    public ApplicationClass() {
        super();
    }

    Tracker mTracker;

    synchronized public Tracker getTracker() {
        GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
        mTracker = analytics.newTracker(R.xml.app_tracker);
        // analytics.getLogger().setLogLevel(LogLevel.VERBOSE);
        return mTracker;
    }

    /**
     * Send a Google Analytics screen hit
     * 
     * @param ScreenName
     *            Name as it appears on the Analytics page
     */
    public void sendScreen(String ScreenName) {
        if (mTracker == null)
            getTracker();

        // Setup a tracker
        Tracker t = mTracker;

        // Set screen name.
        t.setScreenName(ScreenName);

        // Send a screen view.
        t.send(new HitBuilders.AppViewBuilder().build());
    }

    /**
     * Send a Google Analytics event hit
     * 
     * @param ScreenName
     *            Name as it appears on the Analytics page
     */
    public void sendEvent(String EventCategory, String EventAction) {
        if (mTracker == null)
            getTracker();

        // Setup a tracker
        Tracker t = mTracker;

        // Send a event hit.
        t.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder().setCategory(EventCategory)
                .setAction(EventAction).build());
    }
}
```

**app_tracker.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:ignore="TypographyDashes">

    <integer name="ga_sessionTimeout">50</integer>

    <!-- Enable automatic Activity measurement -->
    <bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">false</bool>

    <!-- Enable Uncaught exceptions tracking -->
    <bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>

    <!-- The following value should be replaced with correct property id. -->
    <string name="ga_trackingId">UA-xxxxxxxx-x</string>

</resources>
```

And finally, I send hits from activities like this:

```
((ApplicationClass) getApplication())
                .sendScreen(Param.GA_SCREEN_COURSE);
```

I waited for over a month now!

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any filters in place on the view?

Comment: No. I checked it many times that I have no filters for any views. I never even tried filters actually.

Comment: Not sure if this info could help, I used to have Google Adwords account linked to the same Property. After a month of no hits in Reports, I removed it recently and still, nothing has changed :(

Comment: Please post some code.

Comment: Edited question with codes included. The application is [open source](https://github.com/praveendath92/MDroid)

Comment: Hey, I'm facing the same problem.. Did you solve it? Thanks!

Comment: 5 years has passed but I'm facing exactly the same issue. If anybody knows how to solve this please let me know.